# Add Accounts SubPanel in Meetings Module

Tags: php, sugarcrm

In the Meetings module using Studio I added a relationship to the Account module which is one-to-many. As I save a Meeting entry and add the related-to entry using Accounts, the details of the related Account isn't showing in the Account SubPanel. I am using the latest version of SugarCRM.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a logic hook to achieve your desired results:

custom/modules/Meetings/logic_hooks.php

```
$hook_array['before_save'] = Array();
$hook_array['before_save'][] = Array(1, 'Set Account relationship', 'custom/modules/Meetings/AccountRelationshipHook.php', 'AccountRelationshipHook', 'setAccountRelationship');
$hook_array['before_delete'] = Array();
$hook_array['before_delete'][] = Array(1, 'Remove Account relationship', 'custom/modules/Meetings/AccountRelationshipHook.php', 'AccountRelationshipHook', 'deleteAccountRelationship');
```

Then in your logic hook create methods to use your newly defined relationship 'meetings_accounts' (or whatever you named it) and add or delete the Account record. Since it's one-to-many you want to make sure there is only one Account per Meeting record. Also, for the sake of keeping things tidy, when the Meeting is deleted also delete the record's relationship via the method deleteAccountRelationship().

custom/modules/Meetings/AccountRelationshipHook.php

```
class AccountRelationshipHook {

    public function setAccountRelationship(&$bean, $event, $arguments) {
        if ($bean->parent_type == 'Accounts') {
            $bean->load_relationship('meetings_accounts');
            if ($bean->parent_id != $bean->fetched_row['parent_id']) {
                $bean->meetings_accounts->delete($bean->id, $bean->fetched_row['parent_id']);
            }
            $bean->meetings_accounts->add($bean->parent_id);
        }
    }

    public function deleteAccountRelationship(&$bean, $event, $arguments) {
        if ($bean->parent_type == 'Accounts') {
            $bean->load_relationship('meetings_accounts');
            $bean->meetings_accounts->delete($bean->id, $bean->parent_id);
        }
    }
}
```